# Postgres SQL Get All Permutations Columns

Tags: postgresql

I had a table, call it `items`

```
item_id x 
A       0.1
A       0.2
B       0.25
B       0.35
C       0.4
C       0.5
```

I'm basically looking to get all possible permutations and numbering those permutations. Basically using a join on the table itself with `items_version_a.item_id <> items_version_b.item_id` I was able to get a table that does give all possible combinations (24 rows). I would like to create a column called `iteration`, perhaps that looks something like the following. This would provide a count of the different permutations.

```
item_id x   iteration
A       0.1   1
A       0.1   2
A       0.1   3
A       0.1   4
A       0.2   5
A       0.2   6
A       0.2   7
A       0.2   8
B       0.25  1
B       0.25  2
B       0.25  5
B       0.25  6
B       0.35  3
B       0.35  4
B       0.35  7
B       0.35  8
C       0.4   1
C       0.4   3
C       0.4   5
C       0.4   7
C       0.5   2
C       0.5   4
C       0.5   6
C       0.5   8
```

The ordering doesn't technically matter but I do need the `iteration` column to capture all permutations correctly. But you do see that in the example above, if you were to order by `iteration, item_id` you would get

```
item_id x   iteration
A       0.1     1
B       0.25    1
C       0.4     1
A       0.1     2
B       0.25    2
C       0.5     2
A       0.1     3
B       0.35    3
C       0.4     3
A       0.1     4
B       0.35    4
C       0.5     4
A       0.2     5
B       0.25    5
C       0.4     5
A       0.2     6
B       0.25    6
C       0.5     6
A       0.2     7
B       0.35    7
C       0.4     7
A       0.2     8
B       0.35    8
C       0.5     8
```

And you can see that each of these iterations does capture a unique permutation.

Answer (score 0):

```
select
*
, row_number() over(partition by a.item_id order by b.x, a.x) as iteration
from ( ...
```

You can use ROW_NUMBER() to generate your iteration column, through the OVER(...) clause a change in the partition value resets the counter to 1, and the order by controls how the sequence of the counter increments.

[SQL Fiddle](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!15/0b4d3/5)

**PostgreSQL 9.3 Schema Setup**:

```
CREATE TABLE items
    (item_id varchar(1), x decimal(8,2))
;

INSERT INTO items
    (item_id, x)
VALUES
    ('A', 0.1),
    ('A', 0.2),
    ('B', 0.25),
    ('B', 0.35),
    ('C', 0.4),
    ('C', 0.5)
;
```

**Query 1**:

```
select
      a.item_id
    , a.x
    , row_number() over(partition by a.item_id order by b.x, a.x) as iteration
    , b.x
from items a
inner join items b on a.item_id <> b.item_id
order by
      iteration
    , a.item_id
    , a.x
```

**[Results](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!15/0b4d3/5/0)**:

```
| item_id |    x | iteration |    x |
|---------|------|-----------|------|
|       A |  0.1 |         1 | 0.25 |
|       B | 0.25 |         1 |  0.1 |
|       C |  0.4 |         1 |  0.1 |
|       A |  0.2 |         2 | 0.25 |
|       B | 0.35 |         2 |  0.1 |
|       C |  0.5 |         2 |  0.1 |
|       A |  0.1 |         3 | 0.35 |
|       B | 0.25 |         3 |  0.2 |
|       C |  0.4 |         3 |  0.2 |
|       A |  0.2 |         4 | 0.35 |
|       B | 0.35 |         4 |  0.2 |
|       C |  0.5 |         4 |  0.2 |
|       A |  0.1 |         5 |  0.4 |
|       B | 0.25 |         5 |  0.4 |
|       C |  0.4 |         5 | 0.25 |
|       A |  0.2 |         6 |  0.4 |
|       B | 0.35 |         6 |  0.4 |
|       C |  0.5 |         6 | 0.25 |
|       A |  0.1 |         7 |  0.5 |
|       B | 0.25 |         7 |  0.5 |
|       C |  0.4 |         7 | 0.35 |
|       A |  0.2 |         8 |  0.5 |
|       B | 0.35 |         8 |  0.5 |
|       C |  0.5 |         8 | 0.35 |
```

Comment: I thought about that, but that actually doesn't work. The reason why is that it doesn't actually group the permutations correctly. If you do `row_number() over(partition by a.item_id order by a.x) as iteration` notice that for iteration 1 you would get A = 0.1, B = 0.25, and C = 0.4, but you also get the same for iteration 2

Comment: I wonder if a smaller example with only 2 items as opposed to 3 would help here.

Comment: Hm. Thanks your for response! It looks a bit closer, but still not quite. What is the purpose of the b.x column? In particular, if you look at iteration = 1, it's actually the same as iteration = 3 for item_id, a.x, and iteration.

Comment: b.x is merely displayed so you may see the logic at work.